# Awk won’t search through files in sub directories?

Tags: awk, directory

I'm trying to use awk to search through multiples files for a specific string, but it returns

```
'Example' is a directory: skipped.
```

How can I use awk to search through all subdirectories and files?

Example of usage,

```
awk -F: '$3 ~ /example/' * > C:/out.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with shell globbing and not `awk`.  In order to glob recursively you need to enable the bash `globstar` option.

```
shopt -s globstar
```

> globstar
>
> > If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will
> >         match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
> >         If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and
> >         subdirectories match.

So then you would be able to:

```
awk -F: '$3 ~ /example/' ** > C:/out.txt
```

Note you will still receive the error about the directory itself being skipped but it will also recurse into it.  You can hide errors by redirecting stderr to /dev/null

```
awk -F: '$3 ~ /example/' ** > C:/out.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: i found globbing too slow when there are lots of files (slow in terms of command feedback); whereas using command like `find` to recurse files starts executing immediately

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use `find` in combination with `awk`:

```
find -type f -exec awk -F: '$3 ~ /example/' {} > c:/out.txt \;
```

---

**Note:** `find` is not a simple substitute for `*`, as correctly pointed out in the comments below. You might want to tune your `find` parameters in order to return exactly the fileset you are looking for.

**Note:** only one `>` is still needed (as opposed to `>>`) since it is `find`'s output that gets redirected.

**Note:** if, as it seems, you are using `cmder`, you should be careful to call GNU find and not Windows's `find.exe`. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1219129/unix-find-command-on-cmder-exe-in-windows) for ways to overcome this ambiguity.

Comment: Note that the redirection is not part of the command given to `-exec` and could therefore be moved to after the `\;`. The effect will still be the same. There's also a subtle difference in that the `find` command would find hidden files, while a shell glob by default wouldn't.

Comment: `find` (this answer) is faster than globbing (other answer) it appears (as globbing will first evaluate all the recursion and then start the command execution)